# Orange Infrared

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, orange

I must say Orange has really done great job in the world of machine learning. I have 3 questions.

(1) I have found **"Orange Infrared"** has been added recently. But I haven't found any kind of data regarding infrared spectra. I would like to know how to get that Infrared data? Whether the IR spectra data from **Gaussian** software can be used to be trained in Orange?

(2) I have seen a video orange has Neural Network classifier, But I downloaded and installed orange 3.3.12, No neural network model has been found.

(3) What is CN2 rule Induction, by any means is it related to Convolution Neural Network.

Comment: These are three distinct questions.

Comment: Re CN2, probably unrelated to CNN. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CN2_algorithm

Answer (score 3):

An infrared data set "Collagen spectroscopy" is available in the "Data Sets" widget. There are some other but small data sets in the infrared data folder: the easiest way to find the folder is to search for "peach_juice.dpt".

Orange Infrared can read Opus, Envi, .spa, .nea, Omnic maps, and some ASCII file formats.

Answer (score 1):

Neural Network became available to Orange recently. The version that you have does not have it, and you have to install a newer version (say, the most recent version 3.6.0). Neural Network can be used both for regression and classification, in typical Orange workflow such as that for accuracy estimation with cross-validation (shown below) or class prediction (using Predictions widget.

[image: neural network in orange]